# SSRS, For row groups that yield multiple rows, how to merge duplicate column groups cells

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2012, with a matrix of one columns group, several row groups.  When a Row Group warrants a new row, the column group rows duplicate their values into each row.
[image]

How can I get the values in the column group cells to display once merged into like rows?  So for the "Toots McGee" row, all the cells for A.1, A.2, A.3 would show their respective values once, in merged row cells.

Comment: It is not possible. good luck

Comment: Nothing is impossible.  I can't fire up RS at the moment but I'll put a bet you can check those three columns and merge it in code.